# OSGI: Import-Package could not be resolved

Tags: maven, import, dependencies, osgi, package

I'm trying to deploy a bundle to osgi and I'm getting this error

```
An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: signature; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle....
constraint: <Import-Package: signature; version="0.0.0">

at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.QuasiResolveStage.process(QuasiResolveStage.java:46)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:360)
... 9 common frames omitted
```

I can't find this signature depedency anywhere in maven, since my other dependency issues had full group paths, I've assumed this artifact is only called 'signature'. The other issues I had similar to this one were jline and jess, but had no issues finding those artifacts.

Does anyone know of this artifact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps define a class with this package name in blueprint? The blueprint context is also analysed by the maven bundle plugin.